# Form Method 'GET'. On submit move to Other page then run php file

Tags: php, get, form-submit

What I need to do as concept is quite simple.

**Let's suppose this is my form:**

```
<form name="my_form" class="my_class" id="my_id" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="input1" value="my_text" id="my_id">
<input type="submit" name="button" class="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

I need to perfom those **2 steps**

**Step 1)** On Submit move to page 'http//myformsubmit.eu/form/result'

**Step 2)** 'Run query.php'

I was thinking to add a kind of action like:

```
<form name="my_form"  id="my_id" method="GET" action="/result/query.php">
```

Is this possible? Any way to perform those two steps?

Comment: Are you able to explain it more clearly? Currently it sounds like your checking how to make your form post to `/result/query.php`

Comment: any reason for using `method="GET"`? It sounds like you want more of a post-redirect-get pattern.

Comment: On submit action "http//myformsubmit.eu/form/result/ where it should run the php 'query.php'.

Comment: @ Pitchinnate  ajax run php file on the same page. I need to run it on the moving page.

Comment: @ nullability any special reason to use method get

Comment: I think you have the option running a script access to "query.php" on the result page when it loads?